# Longest path in a tree using k vertices

Tags: algorithm, tree, dynamic-programming

We have a tree with `n (2 <= n <= 1000)` nodes and we need to find `k (1 <= k <= 100 and k <= n - 1)` **distinct** vertices such that the path going through all of these vertices has the maximum length.

Note:

- The path should start at vertex `1` and finish also at vertex `1`.
- The algorithm has to return just the length of the maximum path (the path itself is not needed).
- The path between vertices has to be the shortest path.
- The weight for the edge has following restrictions: `0 <= w <= 100000`.

---

Let's say we have the following tree with `n = 5` vertices:
[image]

We need to find `k = 3` vertices which will give us the longest path.

For this tree the maximal path is the following:
1 ⟶  5 ⟶  2 ⟶  4 ⟶  1

It has the total length of `13 + 18 + 10 + 5 = 46`.
So, for that particular tree we have to print `46` as our result.

---

I came up with a following greedy/dp-like solution.
First we solve the problem for `k = 1` and we remember this solution in a linked list `1 -> v -> 1`. After that we try to solve the problem for `k = 2` by trying all of the remaining `n - 2` vertices and insert it in the current path: `1 -> u -> v -> 1` and `1 -> v -> u -> 1`. After going through all of the vertices we choose the one which gave us the best result. Then we proceed to solve `k = 3`.

The problem is that it looks like [this solution](http://pastebin.com/kvhPSSUw) is not correct, because it fails the tests for [this problem](https://icpcarchive.ecs.baylor.edu/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=633&page=show_problem&problem=5184).
I cannot prove that my solution is correct and I cannot disprove it. All I managed to do is to generate millions of different random trees and in all of these cases my clever solution matched bruteforce solution.

For now all my effort is directed towards generating a counter example in which my method will fail, but if it is correct I'd be glad to see the reasoning why is it correct.

Comment: In your code I can't actually see where you print out the answer?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz I've played a lot with the code, so I forgot about that =) Here is the correct one: http://pastebin.com/kvhPSSUw. I print the result on line #117.

Comment: Having read the linked problem description, I see what you are trying to say, but your problem wording is very misleading: it's not clear that the k vertices are to be visited in order, or that the path from each to the next must be shortest-possible. (As it happens, for a tree, the latter condition would ordinarily be implied, since there's only one simple path between any two vertices in a tree -- but you want a "path" to allow repeated vertices, so it isn't here. BTW, this is *not* standard usage of "path" -- you should explicitly say that repeated vertices are allowed, or use "walk".)

Comment: @j_random_hacker Understood :) I will fix my question in a few hours. By the way, do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: I've looked at it for a while and I'm afraid I don't see a solution yet... Based on how large k and n can be, it can't be efficiently solved by trying all $n \choose k$ possibilities even without caring about their order. A couple of ideas that might be useful: every path in a rooted tree has a unique highest (closest-to-the-root) point; every edge in the tree must be traversed an even number of times (maybe you can try to solve it by choosing traversal counts for each edge and summing them, instead of choosing paths and summing those).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code only stores and extends one of the maximal-length k-solutions.

In the example below, verify that the path 1->5->3->1 is of maximal length. The maximal length extensions of this path are 1->5->3->4->1 and 1->5->2->3->1, both of length 10. However the path 1->5->2->4->1 has length 12.

[image: path containing five vertices]

Comment: 1->5->2->1 is *also* an optimal solution for k=2, so it's possible, @Pixar, that your solution finds it instead of the solution Angela gave, which it can then extend to the optimal length-12 solution.  But you just got lucky -- your program could just as easily have chosen Angela's 1->5->3->1 solution at that earlier step, and then it would have gotten stuck at a suboptimal solution later.